# Spark 2.1 Structured Streaming - Using Kakfa as source with Python (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

With Apache Spark version 2.1, I would like to use Kafka (0.10.0.2.5) as source for Structured Streaming with pyspark:

kafka_app.py:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("TestKakfa").getOrCreate()

kafka=spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:6667") \
.option("subscribe","mytopic").load()
```

I launched the app in the following way:

```
./bin/spark-submit kafka_app.py --master local[4] --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10-2.1.0.jar
```

After having downloaded the .jar from mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10/2.1.0

And I get such error :

```
[...] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Failed to find data source: kakfa. [...]
```

Similarly, I cannot run the Spark example of integration with Kakfa : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

So I wonder where I am wrong or whether Kafka integration with Spark 2.1 using pyspark is actually supported as this page mentioning only Scala and Java as supported language in the version 0.10 makes me doubt : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html
(But if not supported yet, why an example in Python was published ?)

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use sql-structured streaming jar "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.jar" instead of spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10-2.1.0.jar.

Comment: How do you know what version to specify, and the syntax to use? (e.g. I've seen  using `:` and `,` to separate the last part: `2.1.0.jar`. Or, should I specify the last `.jar` part or can I leave it out?)
And how do you know what repository to specify, if any?
(I'm trying to specify these options as --packages in pyspark-sell arguments)